# How can get the maximum value of a sensor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to build a push-ups counter app and i want app to count by using proximity sensor. I'm using the minimum value of proximity to count, that is (0). but I think its better to use the maximum value of proximity sensor to count push-ups. I want to know is it possible to find the maximum value of proximity sensor in programming?

Comment: Try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getMaximumRange()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method to get maximum value of sensor :

```
Float maxvalue = mysensor.getMaximumRange();
```